# Web-services in Android using KSOAP

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I want to create connection of web-services using KSOAP2,I have already done code and its getting error,So please suggest me where i'm doing wrong.also i need some help in web-service regard,What is namespace,method that we call,soap_action,url and also some about methods that we use in web-services.I have searched lot but haven't found any complete description about web-services

```
 public class Web_ServicesActivity extends Activity {
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://service.fun2shoot.com/getLive";

    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://service.fun2shoot.com/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "getLive";

    private static String URL = "http://119.82.75.91:8084/Fun2Shoot-WebService/Fun2ShootAndroid?wsdl";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        System.out
                .println("After mail******************************************");
        // Initialize soap request + add parameters
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        System.out.println("****************After Request call");
        // Use this to add parameters
        // request.addProperty("Parameter","Value");

        // Declare the version of the SOAP request
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        // Needed to make the internet call
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

        if (result != null) {
            TextView t = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            System.out
                    .println("***************************************Inside null condition");
            // Get the first property and change the label text
            t.setText("SOAP response:\n\n" + result.getProperty(0).toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 14 line 8 column you using wrong method if you know what I mean.

Comment: means can u tell me in brief............

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse() Try using this to get the response.

Comment: Error is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Finally I solved that ,When this problem occure we should make a libs folder in Project and add jar file in libs.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what is KSOP, I only know KSOAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can add library in **`Build Path`** of Your Project and for your reference for creating web service in java use this Tutorial [How to create java based web service](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html).

If you have any doubts regarding this or any other doubts you can write me.